# Asynchronous and PARALLEL generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I have python script which lazily collects data, creates training samples and passes it to my ML model for learning. For now I am generating data using standard python generator, which to my knowledge is synchronous. I am looking for a smart clean way to make my generator truly asynchronous so when I use it as iterator, the processing of next data samples will start immediately after I pull last samples out. Consider the following example:

```
def asyncgen():
    for i in range(5):
        print("I want this part to work asynchronously :(")
        i = 0;
        while(i<1e8):
            i+=1
        yield "Hi"

a = asyncgen()
for w in a:
    print(w)
    i = 0
    while (i < 1e8):
        i += 1
```

How do I make my generator to start processing stuff (and asynchronously, under different process) right after I receive "Hi"? Currently the processing starts only after the for cycle calls next().

I have been looking into [Asynchronous generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) PEP 525, but they seem to work only concurrently and not in parallel (damn you GIL!). What is some nice, preferably native way to do this in Python.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://hackernoon.com/asynchronous-python-45df84b82434)?

Comment: @lalengua yes I have read the similar blog and docs. Threads, greenlets and asyncio are all running on single process. And although my "parsing frontend" is doing some io stuff, it is also doing a lot of processing and I dont want to to slow down my computation on the same process. I have enough cores on my machine to run this in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to bypass the GIL is by using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def asynch_part(i):
    print("I want this part to work asynchronously :(")
    k = 0;
    while(k<1e8):
        k+=1
    yield "Hi" # +" from " + str(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p=[]
    for i in range(5): # I am keeping the processes listed and trackable,  
                       # perhaps you do not care. os.getpid() tracks them anyway
        p[i] = Process(target=asynch_part, args=(i))
        p[i].start()

    for i in range(5):
        p[i].join()
```

So in the above code your asyncgen is ran 5 times independently, as parallel processes. Then they they are joined before the program ends. Keeping a list p is just illustrative.

Comment: Well I know about this option, I just hoped there is something more clean :(... So I guess I am going to write a wrapper class, that is iterable, receives generator and calls few items in advance, prepares them into queue, and yields them one by one when its `__next__` method is called, while some background worker will fill the queue when needed.

Comment: Well, no escaping from multiprocessing, unfortunately. The generator seems elegant,

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are a great way to solve this problem too.
Basically, rather than have one program with threads or multi-processes, make an external one that does the async one that you connect to externally.

Learn more about sockets at [PMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html)

Here's a pretty complete example (python 2.7):

```
import argparse
import logging
import socket
import time
import random

description = """
This program sends data across a socket
"""
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description)
arg_parser.add_argument('--AgentIP', '-i', action='store'    
    , default='localhost' , type=str
    , help="The IP address of this Server that client will connect to."
    )
arg_parser.add_argument('--AgentPort', '-p', action='store'     
    , default='13000' , type=int
    , help="The port number of the socket that client will connect to."
    )
arg_parser.add_argument('--log', action='store'     
    , default='INFO' , type=str
    , help="Log level"
    , choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL']
    )
args = arg_parser.parse_args()

# use Logger for great justice and heavenly output
logging.basicConfig(level=getattr(logging, args.log, 'CRITICAL'))
log = logging.getLogger(name='SERVER')

### vvv YOUR CODE vvv ###
def asyncgen(log):
    for i in range(5):
        log.debug("I want this part to work asynchronously :(") 
        time.sleep(random.random())
        yield "Hi"
### ^^^ YOUR CODE ^^^ ###

def make_a_connection(server, log):
    # Accept outside connections
    (client_socket, address) = server.accept()
    log.info("Got a connection : {}:{}".format(client_socket,address))

    for value in asyncgen(log):
        client_socket.send(value)
        log.info("SEND:{}".format(value))

    client_socket.close()


def main(args, log):
    server   = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM )
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    hostname = socket.gethostbyname(args.AgentIP)
    port     = args.AgentPort
    address  = (hostname, port)

    server.bind(address)
    server.listen(1)
    log.info("Server started on {}:{}".format(hostname, port))

    try:
        while True:
          make_a_connection(server, log)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
       server.close()
       log.info("Server connections closed")


if __name__=='__main__':
    main(args, log)
```

Comment: use netcat to take a look at this running.  try `nc localhost 13000`