# Rewrite Python generator as asynchronous

Tags: python, elasticsearch, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a Python script that generates `[str, float]` tuples which are then indexed into ElasticSearch using a custom function which eventually calls [helper.streaming_bulk()](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.1/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk).

This is how the generator is implemented:

```
doc_ids: List[str] = [...]
docs = ((doc_id, get_value(doc_id) for doc_id in doc_ids)
```

`get_value()` calls a remote service that computes a float value per document id.
Next, these tuples are passed on to `update_page_quality_bulk()`:

```
for success, item in update_page_quality_bulk(
        islice(doc_qualities, size)
    ):
        total_success += success
        if not success:
            logging.error(item)
```

Internally, update_page_quality_bulk() creates the ElasticSearch requests.

One of the advantages of using a generator here is that the first `size` elements can be fed into `update_page_quality_bulk()` through [islice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

In order to make the entire process faster, I would like to parallelize the `get_value()` calls. As mentioned, these are remote calls so the local compute cost in negligible, but the duration is significant.

The order of the tuples does not matter, neither which elements are passed into `update_page_quality_bulk()`. On a high level, I would like to make the `get_value()` calls (up to `x` in parallel) for any `n` tuples and pass on whichever ones are finished first.

My naive attempt was to define `get_value()` as asynchronous:

```
async def get_value():
  ...
```

and await the call in the generator:

```
docs = ((doc_id, await get_value(doc_id) for doc_id in doc_ids)
```

However, this raises an error in the subsequent `islice()` call:

```
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

Removing the `islice` call and passing the unmodified `docs` generator to `update_page_quality_bulk()` causes the same error to be raised when looping over the tuples to convert them into ElasticSearch requests.

I am aware that the ElasticSearch client provides [asynchronous helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/async.html#bulk-and-streaming-bulk), but they don't seem applicable here because I need to generate the actions first.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902202/python-async-generator-not-async), it seems like I have to change the implementation to using a queue.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399088/1897839) implies that it cannot be done without using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) due to Python GIL, but that answer is not marked as correct and is quite old too.

Generally, I am looking for a way to change the current logic as little as possible while parallelizing the `get_value()` calls.

Comment: Note: the simplest solution might be to just run the script in parallel `x` times, but I am curious if there is a Pythonistic solution.

Comment: Iterating over an ``async`` generator requires an ``async for`` loop – basically your setup must be ``async`` all the way down. Note though that an ``async`` generator still computes one element after the other – it merely allows *other* tasks (with their own ``async`` generators or coroutines or ...) to run concurrently. Depending on the async framework you are using, something like ``asyncio.gather`` would be more suitable than an async generator. (That is to say, an async generator is not suitable at all.)

Comment: With what the question currently contains, we can tell you how to rig up the code in such a way that the async generator is run correctly. *This will likely not solve your problem*: 1) An async generator does not provide parallelism. 2) If the work is done by a synchronous function like ``streaming_bulk``, an async framework must use threads for it. So you would be better of just to directly use threads.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to pass an "synchronous looking" generator to a call that expects a normal lazy generator such as islice, and keep getting the results for this in parallel.

It sounds like a work for `asyncio.as_completed`: you use your plain generator to create tasks - these are run in parallel by the asyncio machinery, and the results are made available as the tasks are completed (d'oh!).

However since `update_page_quality_bulk` is not asynco aware, it will never yield the control to the asyncio loop, so that it can complete the tasks which got their results.  This would likely block.

Calling `update_page_quality_bulk` in another thread probably won't work as well. I did not try it here, but I'd say you can't just iterate over [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) in a different thread than the one it (and its tasks) where created.

So, first things first - the "generator expression" syntax does not work when you want some terms of the generator to be calculated asynchronously, as you found out - we refactor that so that the tuples are created in an coroutine-function - and we wrap all calls for those in tasks (some of the asyncio functions do the wrapping in a task automatically)

Then we can us the asyncio machinery to schedule all the calls and call `update_page_quality_bulk` as these results arrive. The problem is that `as_completed`, as stated above, can't be passed directly to a non-async function: the asyncio loop would never get control back. Instead, we keep picking the results of tasks in the main thread, and call the sync function in another thread - using a Queue to pass the fetched results. And finally, so that the results can be consumed as made available inside `update_page_quality_bulk`, we create a small wrapper class to the threading.Queue, so that it can be consumed as in iterator - this is transparent for the code consuming the iterator.

```py
# example code: untested

async def get_doc_values(doc_id):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    # Run_in_executor runs the synchronous function in parallel in a thread-pool
    # check the docs - you might want to pass a custom executor with more than
    # the default number of workers, instead of None:
    return doc_id, await asyncio.run_in_executor(None, get_value, doc_id)


def update_es(iterator):
    # this function runs in a separate thread - 
    for success, item in update_page_quality_bulk(iterator):
            total_success += success
            if not success:
                logging.error(item)
                
sentinel = Ellipsis  # ... : python ellipsis - a nice sentinel that also worker for multiprocessing

class Iterator:
    """This allows the queue, fed in the main thread by the tasks as they are as they are completed
    to behave like an ordinary iterator, which can be consumed by "update_page_quality_bulk" in another thread
    """
    def __init__(self, source_queue):
        self.source = source_queue
        
        
    def __next__(self):
        value= self.source.get()
        if value is sentinel:
            raise StopIteration()
        return value


queue = threading.Queue()
iterator = Iterator(queue)
es_worker = threading.Thread(target=update_es, args=(iterator,))
es_worker.start()
for doc_value_task in asyncio.as_completed(get_doc_values(doc_id) for doc_id in doc_ids):
    doc_value = await doc_value_task
    queue.put(doc_value)
    
es_worker.join()
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was: divide the input into chunks of the size of a reasonable bulk request (500 in this case). Then process each input chunk in a thread pool with pool.map, and feed the resulting list into helpers.bulk(). This did require rewriting large portions of the logic, but I do understand that there is no Pythonic parallelized solution in line with my original implementation using generators.